# How to open external app file in React Native

Tags: react-native

Using the package **react-native-receive-sharing-intent**, I receive this intent from the Obisidan app when a page is shared:

```
{
    "contentUri": "content://md.obsidian.fileprovider/my_images/Documents/Myoas/Hello%20obsidian.md", 
    "fileName": "Hello obsidian.md", 
    "filePath": "/data/user/0/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxx/cache/Hello obsidian.md", 
    "mimeType": "text/markdown", 
    "subject": null, 
    "text": null, 
    "weblink": null
}
```

Now my goal is to **open programmatically the Obsidian app showing the same file**.

I tried that but it is not working. This opens the web browser and gives an error:

```
import { Linking } from "react-native";
Linking.openURL("content://md.obsidian.fileprovider/my_images/Documents/Myoas/Hello%20obsidian.md");
```

I don't want a copy of the file or open the markdown file in my app.

I want to open the original file in the external app.

Answer (score 1):

I find a solution [here](https://help.obsidian.md/Advanced+topics/Using+obsidian+URI):

```
Linking.openUrl("obsidian://action?param1=value&param2=value")
```